# Why is overflow:hidden not hiding?

Tags: html, css

The objective of the HTML below is to have on the same horizontal line the red and the blue divs, even thought the blue div is truncated on the right due to a large width. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/me4gj/4/) shows that even though the black/container style has `overflow:hidden` the blue div is not truncated. What's wrong with this HTML?

```
<div id="row1" style="width:600px;height:100px;background-color:black;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="c1" style="width:400px;height:30px;background-color:red;float:left">aaaa</div>
    <div id="c2" style="width:400px;height:30px;background-color:blue;float:left">bbbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to hide out here, inner div is much smaller than outer div

Comment: `div`s force a line break as their default display property is `block`.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4n23D/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floated elements will stack horizontally until the edge of their parent container is reached. At that point, the next floated element will fall down to the next line and the remaining elements will again stack next to each other.

In order to achieve the effect you're looking for, you're going to need a parent container for the floats that is wide enough to contain all the floats.

THEN, and only then, can you place another container around the parent that will clip the overflow.

```
<div id="row1" style="width:600px;height:100px;background-color:black;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="width:800px">
        <div id="c1" style="width:400px;height:30px;background-color:red;float:left">aaaa</div>
        <div id="c2" style="width:400px;height:30px;background-color:blue;float:left">bbbb</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/me4gj/7/

Answer (score 0):

Floats bump down to the next line when there isn't sufficient room in the parent to contain them.

Answer (score 0):

When you use float: and the parent div or object doesn't have the space to go ahead and display it all it just displays everything on the next line or into the next area.

Maybe just adding some more to your height values would fix it or subsequently toning down the size of the objects included in that area.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the inner divs are wrapping because of the width of container -- which is the basic behavior of float.
Also, "overflow:hidden" works in a different way in your code.
When contents have float: left or right and the container has overflow:hidden, then the container automatically wraps whole the contents instead of hiding contents.
For more details, please check out [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)